# Virtual assistant python

Tags: python, python-3.9

Hello everyone I am trying to develop a virtual assistant which will help me with some projects so I am trying to get the basics for the final project however I get an error (UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment) and I tried to change `return command` to under the `printf(command)` but it does not let me talk and a message NONE and the other error which is (TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable) appears on the terminal.
So how can I make this work without stop?

CODE BELOW:

````
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()

def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'skor' in command:
                command = command.replace ('skor', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command
def run_skor():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play on youtube' in command:
        song = command.replace ('play on youtube', '')
        talk('playing' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'search on google' in command:
        sea = command.replace ('search on google', '')
        talk ('searching' + sea)
        pywhatkit.search(sea)
    elif 'tell me the time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
        print(time)
        talk('Current time is' + time)
while True:
    run_skor()```
````

Comment: Add `command=None` as first line of `take_command` or move `return` clause into `try` block. Now your command variable is not defined outside of try block if exception occurs. If you put `return` into try block, then function will return it on success or return None in case of exception (as no return clause will be reached).

Comment: you mean ```command=none``` below def right?I did that and it only gives me none and (TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable), also tried to move ```return``` into try but a new error happens (TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable)

Answer (score 0):

The only change you need to make is in the `take_command()` function. This is my version of it:

```py
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'skor' in command:
                command = command.replace ('skor', '')
                print(command)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        command = ""
    return command
```

Basically, you can first change the execpt command, to be more specific. `sr` has a built in command called `UnknownValueError`. We can use this to be more specific as to when the except command should work. Then, in `except`, set command to `""`. This will stop the errors, because when command is returned, it still is a string, and will still work.

Comment: It worked mate thank you so much, however what happened is the increase of delay when I talk i mean it takes like 15 seconds to the code get the voice command which didnt hapen before

Comment: Mmmmm that's weird. Well, that doesn't happen to me, so I suppose its a computer error.

Comment: It occurs sometims, but it is working thank youu ;) my other problems the youtube command does not open youtube page but seems to be the llbrary error

Comment: You could use the `webrowser` built in module.

Answer (score 0):

```
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        audio = r.listen(source)

        try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        command = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {command}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Say that again please...")
        return "None"

    return command.lower()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for providing that however there is some errors next to try but if I ident it ikeeps not working

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: It takes command, if it is not recognizable then it prints say again :{)